# Colab suddenly slows down a lot after a few iterations while training with Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am trying to train a ResNet50 on Colab and after ~100 batches of the first epoch the remaining time jumps from 4 minutes to 1 hour and 30 minutes.

Yesterday I was training an identical net and I didn't have any problem in doing so with the training going smoothly for the whole 40 epochs. I was trying to implement some data augmentation but I kept encountering this problem: even after going back to the original design the problem persists. What could be the cause?

I am using a GPU runtime, down here you can find the code.
Thanks in advance for the help.

DataLoader:

```
train_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
    #transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
    #transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(p = 0.5),
    transforms.ToTensor()
])

test_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
    transforms.ToTensor()
])

def make_data_loader(args):

    dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(args.data)
    
    train_data_percentage = 0.8
    train_size = int(train_data_percentage * len(dataset))
    test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
    
    train_dataset, test_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset, [train_size, test_size])

    train_dataset.dataset.transform = train_transform
    test_dataset.dataset.transform = test_transform

    train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=True)
    test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=args.val_batch_size, shuffle=False)
    
    return train_loader, test_loader
```

Training

```
def train(args, data_loader, test_loader, model):
    
    criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=args.learning_rate)    

    for epoch in range(args.epochs):
        train_losses = [] 
        train_acc = 0.0
        total=0
        print(f"[Epoch {epoch+1} / {args.epochs}]")
        
        model.train()
        pbar = tqdm(data_loader)
        for i, (x, y) in enumerate(pbar):
            image = x.to(args.device)
            label = y.to(args.device) 
                     
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            output = model(image)
            label = label.squeeze()
            
            loss = criterion(output, label)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            train_losses.append(loss.item())
            total += label.size(0)

            train_acc += acc(output, label)

        epoch_train_loss = np.mean(train_losses)
        epoch_train_acc = train_acc/total

        print(f'Epoch {epoch+1}') 
        print(f'train_loss : {epoch_train_loss}')
        print('train_accuracy : {:.3f}'.format(epoch_train_acc*100))
        
        if epoch%2==0:
          model.eval()
          pred, true = test(args, test_loader, model)
          val_accuracy = (true == pred).sum() / len(pred)
          print("Validation Accuracy : {:.5f}".format(val_accuracy))
        
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), f'{args.save_path}/model.pth')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='ResNet50')
    parser.add_argument('--load-model', default='checkpoints/model.pth', help="Model's state_dict")
    parser.add_argument('--save-path', default='checkpoints/', help="Model's state_dict")
    parser.add_argument('--data', default='data/', type=str, help='data folder')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    args.device = device

    
    # hyperparameters
    args.epochs = 40
    args.learning_rate = 0.1
    args.batch_size = 32
    args.val_batch_size = 4

    # check settings
    print("==============================")
    print("Save path:", args.save_path)
    print('Using Device:', device)
    print('Number of usable GPUs:', torch.cuda.device_count())
    
    # Print Hyperparameter
    print("Batch_size:", args.batch_size)
    print("learning_rate:", args.learning_rate)
    print("Epochs:", args.epochs)
    print("==============================")
    
    # Make Data loader and Model
    train_loader, test_loader = make_data_loader(args)
    
    # new torchvision model
    model = resnet50(weights=ResNet50_Weights)
   
    model.fc.out_features=NUM_CLASSES
    model.to(device)
    print(model)

    # Training The Model
    train(args, train_loader,test_loader, model)
```

I already tried restoring the original implementation and restarting the runtime.